# What's the 日本語 equivalent of "~ism"? (ex. Capitalism, Catholicism, Marxism, etc.)

Tags: words, syntax

What's the Japanese equivalent of the English conjugation "~ism"? Like in things like Capitalism, Socialism, Islamism, Catholicism, Liberalism, Atheism, etc.?

Comment: That also covers _criticism_, _cannibalism_ and _colloquialism_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

～主義 and ～論 are good candidates.

- Capitalism　--　資本主義
- Socialism　--　社会主義
- Islamism　--　イスラム主義
- Catholicism　--　カトリック主義
- Liberalism　--　自由主義
- Existentialism　--　実存主義
- Idealism　--　観念主義
- Altruism　--　博愛主義
- Egoism　-- 利己主義
- Atheism　--　無神論
- Polytheism　--　多神論
- Relativism　--　相対論
- Spiritualism　--　唯心論
- Materialism　--　唯物論

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't work for all your examples, but would probably be understood. Add 〜主義{しゅぎ} to the end of the word.

- 資本主義{しほんしゅぎ}: capitalism
- 社会主義{しゃかいしゅぎ}: socialism
- イスラム主義{しゅぎ}: Islamism
- 自由主義{じゆうしゅぎ}: liberalism

But:

- 無神論{むしんろん} atheism (lit. no god theory/argument)
- カトリシズム: Catholicism (using the English loan 〜イズム)